# A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Getting this error when I run my project in new PC. TO avoid this I have to copy paste the new Connection string every time .. Is there any way to avoid that ... I have 3 different database and its very annoying O_O

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\\Users\\Yoro\\Desktop\\WAPent 3.0 (1)\\WAPent 3.0\\WAPent 3.0\\WAPent 2.0\\WAPent 2.0\\App_Data\\LoginStuff.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
```

Web Config code

```
    <connectionStrings>
  <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\LoginStuff.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Set the connection string in the web.config like the others and reference it by name using `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionString[]`?

Answer (score 4):

In the web.config you are using |DataDirectory| which is a substitution for the path to the datadirectory. This is set by using

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", newpath)
```

When you do not set |DataDirectory| it defaults to the App_Data folder when it is a web project.
So looking at your code the path represented by DataDirectory probably does not contain the database file.

For more info about datadirectory have a look at this (older) [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smartclientdata/archive/2005/08/26/456886.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Open server explorer, right-click on your database, select properties on bottom right corner. A property window will appear; copy the connection string there and use it in your application. For example, in my application:

```
SqlConnection sconnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Taha\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Finder\Finder\App_Data\Userdb.mdf;
Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework");

sconnection.Open();
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue generally occurs in VS 2012 which I too have faced it.
In order to resolve it,you need to foolow these steps:
1)Right Click on the .mdf file ->Select Modify connections under server Explorer.
2)Popup window will come->Click Advanced Button ->Select (LocalDB)\v11.0 as DataSource value

[image]
[image]

Also make sure you make changes in webconfig file as well for DataSource=(LocalDB)\v11.0
You are done.Wella!!

Comment: what if there IS no mdf file to click on?

Answer (score 0):

First, your Database must be in other location than bin folder from your project;
Then, your connection must be declared like this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(TABLE1TableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString);
```

If you have a DataGridView you can click on Choose Data Scource, and add your table as source from your database.(In my example, the table is named TABLE1.) Then, visual studio automatly create a DataSet, DataBinding, and a TableAdapter. The TableAdapter (TABLE1TableAdapter) contains as property the ConnectionString you need for database.
 P.S. I had this problem, and after a lot of work, i find this solution. I hope it helps you too.

Comment: Why must my database be in another location than the bin folder?

Answer (score 0):

You should check your connection string. when you try to attach sql file the connection string should be like that:
**DataSource=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|PharmacyDB.mdf;Database=PharmacyDB;Integrated Security=True**

Answer (score 0):

I get this error when I use two connection string in my same DBContext,for example I try to Connect to sql server in a connection string and connect to sql express file in another connection string:

```
    public MyDBContext(bool autoDetectChangesEnabled)
    : base("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\MyDB.mdf;User Instance=false;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True")
    {
        Initialize(autoDetectChangesEnabled);
    }

    public MyDBContext()
     : base("data source=(LOCAL)\\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=MyDB;persist security info=True;user id=user;password=pass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework")
    {
        Initialize(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Realizing I'm resurrecting an old topic, but my search led me here and the solution that worked for me was not covered in the responses.

I'm using an mdf file as my project's database and by using the Server Explorer in VS I was accurately building my connection string with the following:

```
string _connectionString = $"Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename={System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Database.mdf"};Integrated Security=True";
```

Seemed correct, but I was still receiving this same error. After some trial and error, I found that the issue was not the connection string, but rather the mdf file properties. The setting "Copy to Output Directory" was set to "Do not copy" initially. Setting this to "Copy if newer" fixed the issue for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just clean the solution and then rebuild it. It works well.

Answer (score -1):

Exit Visual Studio.

Run Visual Studio again.

Do not open your project from last program list, open it using the *open project -> browse* procedure.

Go to server explorer: if your .mdf file icon has a little red X, then create a new table, no need to enter anything in the table. Just update it.

First you will see a prompt: choose *NO*.

In the second prompt, choose *YES*: the little red X should go away.

Delete the table you just created and update.

This solved the problem for me.

Comment: Please Don't Use This Capitalization Style. (irony added for effect) Also newlines.