# How do I solve System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException error on ASP.net?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am doing a web application that involves adding data into an existing database row, in my case I want it such that when I click on a button, the data gets inserted into the columns with NULL values.

I have a page that enables users to select the date and number of people going for the tour, and when they click on the "Book Now" button the date and person data should be added into the database.

However when I click on the button, this error appears as:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C: \Users\xxx\Documents\xxx\Project\App_Data\Database.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.'
```

My friend said that to solve this error I would need to delete my current database and redo the whole database again, but I find it very time consuming and tedious as I already set up a big database.

These is the codes I have for the button:

```
    protected void bookBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C: \Users\xxx\Documents\XXX\Project\App_Data\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
    //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Booking",con);
    //not sure if this is correct
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Tours set date = + '"+dateTextbox.Text+"', person = '"+personDLL.Text+"' Where tourName=@tourName");
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", dateTextbox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("person", personDLL.Text);




    con.Open(); //error here
    int k = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (k != 0)
    {
       lblmsg.Text = "Record Inserted Succesfully into the Database";
       lblmsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.CornflowerBlue;
    }
    con.Close();

 }
```

Is there any way that I can solve the following error without having to redo my entire database?

*I only have ONE Database, no duplicated ones

*As I do not have 10 reputtation stackOverflow does not allow me to upload images for better illustration, sorry about that

Comment: Why there is a space after **C:** in  **C: \Users\g_jes\...** ?

Comment: If I removed the space there would be error, the database cannot be executed. I have tried this before @maddy23285

Answer (score 0):

try using 'Initial Catalog' instead of AttachDbFilename in your connection string like this :

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=C: \Users\g_jes\Documents\Gilberte Jessie\aspjProject\App_Data\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
```

Comment: Sorry this did not work, I get a new error saying "Cannot open database requested by login" @Mohammad

Comment: jes, your connection string C: \ has a space

Comment: @depressedGirl that is an authentication issue, check your DB authentication .

Comment: what do you mean by DB authentication, I can access the db until the point when I click on the button @Mohammad

Comment: You are currently using Windows authentication to log in SQL .Create a separate user using SQL authentication and then try to login with this connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is SQL database, Your connection string should look like...

Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=;Integrated Security=True

This will refer to sql server instance and locate your database mentioned in 
    “your database name”

Still want to refer full path of database!!
Checkout this existing post: [A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641883/a-database-with-the-same-name-exists-or-specified-file-cannot-be-opened-or-it)

Comment: I just copied directly the connection string of my database